# Android list view as notification in notification bar using remote views

Tags: android, android-activity

unable to add list view in notification using remote views,is there any other way to display list view in notification bar as notification. Unable to add listview in remote view, Thanks in advance....

```
Notification.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    foregroundNote = mNotifyBuilder.setContentTitle("Call is in progres")
            .setContentText("Slide down on note to expand").setContent(bigView).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.presence_sb_pending).setWhen(when).build();

        NotificationManager mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, 
              R.layout.notification, countryArray);

              ListView listView = (ListView)(DroidApiManager.getInstance().getApplicationActivity()).findViewById(R.id.country_list);
              listView.setAdapter(adapter);
              RemoteViews historylistView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.history_list);

              historylistView.setTextViewText(R.id.callType, listView.toString());

            foregroundNote.bigContentView = historylistView;
              mNotifyManager.notify(1, foregroundNote);
```